# Live detect of variable change

Tags: python

Is it possible to set up a loop with live variable changes? I'm using threading, and the variables can change very often in between lines.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
length = len(some_list)
while length == len(some_list):
    if check_something(some_list):
        # The variable could change right here for 
        # example, and the next line would still be called.
        do_something(some_list)
```

So far I've had no luck, is this something that's possible in python?

EDIT: More what I'm looking for is something so that the loop restarts if `some_list` changes.

Comment: Someone's going to come by and suggest a Queue and I'm going to breakdown because I was beating my head against a wall trying to get a thread that returns a value simultaneously with a progress bar that waits for the value to be returned TT

Comment: How about a queue?

Comment: Have you tried a queue?

Comment: Are these variables related? If you need to read them together in a certain state, you could use a lock to protect them and make a local copy in the thread.

Comment: @Eric  - too late! I'm the first in this dogpile.

Comment: @tdelaney and Eric I can't tell if you guys are being sarcastic or not because of Charlie Gs comment.

Comment: I saw your comment before posting too =)

Comment: I think we both were sarcastic because of Charlie G comment

Comment: Yep, I was indulging in a little desensitization for our Queue-o-phobic friend.

Comment: What's in the list? int, str, ... your own objects?

Comment: @tdelaney It's a dictionary with a function, class and some more variables in it.

Comment: Sorry @CharlieG, I used a queue after all. I feel the same way about beets.

Comment: @tdelaney I laughed my ass off. Back to the Queue tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just a single changing list, you can make a local copy.

```
def my_worker():
    my_list = some_list[:]
    if check_something(my_list):
        do_something(my_list)
```

**UPDATE**

A queue may work for you. The thing that modifies needs to post to the queue, so its not an automatic thing. There is also the risk that the background thread falls behind and processes old stuff or ends up crashing everything if memory is exhausted by the queue.

```
import threading
import queue
import time

def worker(work_q):
    while True:
        some_list = work_q.get()
        if some_list is None:
            print('exiting')
            return
        print(some_list)

work_q = queue.Queue()
work_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(work_q,))
work_thread.start()

for i in range(10):
    some_list.append(i)
    work_q.put(some_list[:])
    time.sleep(.2)
work_q.put(None)

work_thread.join()
```

Comment: Well, what I need is it to have live updating, so if the variable changes, then it'll restart the loop. I'll edit my post.

Comment: If the list is being written while you copy it, won't it throw?

Comment: @Eric - python won't release the GIL during the copy so its thread safe. It would be different if I was doing something like appending in a loop.

Comment: @KepoorHampond - then maybe you do want queuing. Is the list large? Do you want to do work on any change to the list? Is it only based on its size changing or values too?

Comment: I'll trust you on this one, here's +10

Comment: @tdelaney Maybe queuing is what I want, I don't really know, I'm new to threading. It's both value and size unfortunately.

Comment: I think this'll work for my problem, and if it doesn't, then it still answers the question!